# Running ML algorithm dynamically in Python

Tags: python, dynamic

I have dataframe that looks like this

```
id    Alg
--------------
1     RandomForestClassifier(max_features="sqrt", n_jobs=3) 
2     LogisticRegression(C=0.1, solver="liblinear")
3     RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000) 
4     LogisticRegression(C=1.0, solver="liblinear")
.
.
```

I want to build these models dynamically so I have this code

```
for i in df["id"]:
    print("i = " + str(i))
    Alg =  str(df[df["id"]==i]["Alg"]).strip()
    clf = eval(Alg)
```

but I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 9, in <module>
File "<string>", line 1
1    RandomForestClassifier()
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Here is what I tried

1- Add 4 spaces before the algorithm name (did not work)

```
    Alg =  "    " + str(df[df["id"]==i]["Alg"]).strip()
```

2- Replaced the algorithm with 1+1 (worked clf value was 2)

```
    Alg =  "1+1" #+ str(df[df["id"]==i]["Alg"]).strip()
```

Comment: Your `eval` does not inherit your globals.  It starts out with an empty environment  Thus, none of those names will be defined.  You should NOT be storing Python code in a dataframe.  Store codes that let you call the corresponding functions in your own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this solution.  Instead of a function call, I store a list with a function name and a dictionary with all of the parameters.  I then use the safe `ast.literal_eval` to parse that (although you could do it with JSON, too), and pass the parameters to the appropriate function:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

names = [
     "['RandomForestClassifier',{'max_features':'sqrt', 'n_jobs':3}]",
     "['LogisticRegression',{'C':0.1, 'solver':'liblinear'}]",
     "['RandomForestClassifier',{'n_estimators':1000}]",
     "['LogisticRegression',{'C':1.0,'solver':'liblinear'}]"
 ]

df = pd.DataFrame( names, columns=['Alg'] )

def RandomForestClassifier( **kwargs ):
    print( "Received", kwargs )

def LogisticRegression( **kwargs ):
    print( "Received", kwargs )

for row in df['Alg']:
    info = ast.literal_eval(row)
    print(info)
    if info[0] == 'RandomForestClassifier':
        clf = RandomForestClassifier( **info[1] )
    elif info[0] == 'LogisticRegression':
        clf = LogisticRegression( **info[1] )
```

Output:

```
['RandomForestClassifier', {'max_features': 'sqrt', 'n_jobs': 3}]
Received {'max_features': 'sqrt', 'n_jobs': 3}
['LogisticRegression', {'C': 0.1, 'solver': 'liblinear'}]
Received {'C': 0.1, 'solver': 'liblinear'}
['RandomForestClassifier', {'n_estimators': 1000}]
Received {'n_estimators': 1000}
['LogisticRegression', {'C': 1.0, 'solver': 'liblinear'}]
Received {'C': 1.0, 'solver': 'liblinear'}
```

Comment: Can I pass the parameters as string to an algorithm?
if Alg[0:22]=="RandomForestClassifier"
     clf = RandomForestClassifier( Alg[23:-1] )

Comment: No.  Who would interpret that?  No, named parameters must be supplied as a dictionary.  The code I've supplied is not that awful, and it is easily extended.